# How do I make columns in a responsive design clear properly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to figure out responsive design and made a simple layout with 4 columns, each 25% each.  At a very small size, I have a media query that makes them all 100% and they stack on top of each other.

Where I'm stuck is in a middle size (above 480px for example).  I want the four columns to be 50% of the page each so if I have a row with four column divs, it would show 2 x 2.  The problem is, the third one doesn't clear.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns"><p>Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns Four columns </p></div>
        <div class="four columns"><p>Four columns2 Four columns2 Four columns2 Four columns2 Four columns2 Four columns2 Four columns2 Four columns2 </p></div>
        <div class="four columns"><p>Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 Four columns3 </p></div>
        <div class="four columns"><p>Four columns4 Four columns4 Four columns4 Four columns4 Four columns4 Four columns4 </p></div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container { 
background-color:#fff;
margin:0 auto;
width: 95%;
border:1px solid #ff0000;
}

.row {
float: left;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}

 .container .columns {
float: left;
padding: 0 16px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

 .clearfix:after,
.container:after {
content: ' ';
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: hidden;
width:  0;
height: 0;
clear:  both;
}

 .clearfix,
 .container {
zoom:   1;
}
```

/*  BASIC COLUMNS FOR SMALLEST SIZE
/*****************************************/

```
.container .columns.one,
.container .columns.two,
.container .columns.three,
.container .columns.four,
.container .columns.five,
.container .columns.six,
.container .columns.seven,
.container .columns.eight,
.container .columns.nine,
.container .columns.ten,
.container .columns.eleven,
.container .columns.twelve,
.container .columns.thirteen,
.container .columns.fourteen,
.container .columns.fifteen,
.container .columns.sixteen,
.container .columns.one-third   {   width: 100%;    }

.container { width: 100%; }
```

@media screen and (min-width:480px) {

```
.container .columns.one         {   width: 6.25%;   }
.container .columns.two         {   width: 12.5%;   }
.container .columns.three       {   width: 18.75%;  }
.container .columns.four        {   width: 50%;     }
.container .columns.five        {   width: 31.25%;  }
.container .columns.six         {   width: 37.5%;   }
.container .columns.seven       {   width: 43.75%;  }
.container .columns.eight       {   width: 50%;     }
.container .columns.nine        {   width: 56.25%;  }
.container .columns.ten         {   width: 62.5%;   }
.container .columns.eleven      {   width: 68.75%;  }
.container .columns.twelve      {   width: 75%;     }
.container .columns.thirteen    {   width: 81.25%;  }
.container .columns.fourteen    {   width: 87.5%;   }
.container .columns.fifteen     {   width: 93.75%;  }
.container .columns.sixteen     {   width: 100%;    }
.container .columns.one-third   {   width: 33.333333333333333%;     }

.container {
    width: 95%;
}
```

}

@media screen and (min-width:800px) {

```
.container .columns.one         {   width: 6.25%;   }
.container .columns.two         {   width: 12.5%;   }
.container .columns.three       {   width: 18.75%;  }
.container .columns.four        {   width: 25%;     }
.container .columns.five        {   width: 31.25%;  }
.container .columns.six         {   width: 37.5%;   }
.container .columns.seven       {   width: 43.75%;  }
.container .columns.eight       {   width: 50%;     }
.container .columns.nine        {   width: 56.25%;  }
.container .columns.ten         {   width: 62.5%;   }
.container .columns.eleven      {   width: 68.75%;  }
.container .columns.twelve      {   width: 75%;     }
.container .columns.thirteen    {   width: 81.25%;  }
.container .columns.fourteen    {   width: 87.5%;   }
.container .columns.fifteen     {   width: 93.75%;  }
.container .columns.sixteen     {   width: 100%;    }
.container .columns.one-third   {   width: 33.333333333333333%;     }

.container {
    width: 95%;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `float` properties with `display: inline-block;`

This places your elements inline (beside each other) while retaining the sizing properties of block elements.

So, putting a 25% width on your columns would place them all beside each other, and keep them in the page flow, unlike floating.

Put in a media query to change them to 50% width, and they will automatically break to the next line which has enough space to fit them.

Note that you may need to use `vertical-align: top;` to prevent them from lining up at the baseline. (I really feel like this should have been the default, but oh well)

See demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/DuGde/